# Draw complex element in Flutter with path, then redraw this same element in different angles

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, bezier

I need to paint the following widget in Flutter:

[image]

I've already come with with a way to draw those tic-tacs:

```
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width * 2, size.height * 0.05);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 2, size.height * 0.05, size.width,
        size.height * 0.05, size.width, size.height * 0.05);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.05, size.width, size.height * 1.05,
        size.width, size.height * 1.05);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 1.05, size.width * 2,
        size.height * 1.05, size.width * 2, size.height * 1.05);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 2, size.height * 1.05, size.width * 2,
        size.height * 0.05, size.width * 2, size.height * 0.05);
```

However, this tic-tac is an horizontal one. I need to draw multiple of them, and with different angles. The mathematics of where to put each one is simple trigonometry (sines and cosines with a lenght). The angle that each one should make is the angle of the sine/cosine. However, drawing many of them with Flutter's clipping tool is hard.

**Is there a way to draw one complex element in flutter using path and then redraw it in different places with a slight rotation?**

If no, which other technique should I employ?

Comment: Why do you need to paint that? Why don't you use the shape as `png` image or `svg`?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi I though using a .png would be a bad idea, mostly because of different resolutions but also performance if needed to change state fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape is a rectangle with rounded borders. You can use CustomPaint. Please see the code below or directly run it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/e0792a6ab7c9ff3aa1516bfeb77c3886) here >> https://dartpad.dev/e0792a6ab7c9ff3aa1516bfeb77c3886

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: PillPainter(
            circleSize: 100,
            pillWidth: 11,
            pillHeight: 20,
            distanceBetweenPills: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PillPainter extends CustomPainter {
  PillPainter({
    this.circleSize,
    this.pillWidth,
    this.pillHeight,
    this.distanceBetweenPills,
  });
  double circleSize;
  double pillWidth;
  double pillHeight;
  int distanceBetweenPills;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double rotationFactor = 1.75;
    final double numOfPills = 360 / distanceBetweenPills;

    final Paint innerPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.orange
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final Path path = Path();

    final double rotationAngle = rotationFactor * pi;
    final double initialDisplacement = 0.75 * pi;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPills; i++) {
      path.addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectXY(
            Rect.fromCenter(
                center: Offset(
                    size.width / 2 +
                        circleSize * cos(initialDisplacement + rotationAngle),
                    size.height / 2 +
                        circleSize * sin(initialDisplacement + rotationAngle)),
                width: pillWidth,
                height: pillHeight),
            20,
            20),
      );
      canvas.rotate((distanceBetweenPills * pi) / 180);
      innerPaint.color = i % 2 == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
      canvas.drawPath(path, innerPaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```